# Libgdx: Draw a texture with tilemap

Tags: java, libgdx

I have very simple question. But i couldnt solve. I just want to draw a texture on the tilemap. With theese codes i can see the map and move, but i cant see texture.

Here is the screen:

```
package com.adsiz.areyoualive.screen;

import com.adsiz.areyoualive.game.Player;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class PlayScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{
    public ScreenManager screenManager;
    public static float speed = 32;

    //tilemap & camera
    TiledMap tiledMap;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    TiledMapRenderer renderer;
    //player
    Player player;
    //spritebatch
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public PlayScreen(){
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, w, h);
        camera.update();

        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map/untitled.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

        camera.position.set(0, 3200, 0);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        player = new Player(0, 3200);
        spriteBatch.setTransformMatrix(camera.combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        camera.update();
        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();

        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        spriteBatch.begin();
        player.draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        switch (keycode) {
        case Keys.DOWN:
            camera.translate(0, -1*speed);
            player.moveDown();
            break;
        case Keys.UP:
            camera.translate(0, speed);
            player.moveUp();
            break;
        case Keys.LEFT:
            camera.translate(-1*speed, 0);
            player.moveLeft();
            break;
        case Keys.RIGHT:
            camera.translate(speed, 0);
            player.moveRight();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

and here is my player.draw function:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
        batch.draw(playerTexture, getPosX(), getPosY(), playerTexture.getWidth(), playerTexture.getHeight());
    }
```

i just want to show a simple texture and move it on the screen. What is wrong above there? May you help me?

Regards Guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own problem, I just changed map renderer to OrthogonalTileMapRenderer, and changed SpriteBatch's with Batch of OrthogonalTileMapRenderer.

```
package com.adsiz.areyoualive.screen;

import com.adsiz.areyoualive.game.Player;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class PlayScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{
    public ScreenManager screenManager;
    public static float speed = 32;

    //tilemap & camera
    TiledMap tiledMap;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    //player
    Player player;

    public PlayScreen(){
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, w, h);
        camera.update();

        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map/untitled.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);

        camera.position.set(0, 3200, 0);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        player = new Player(0, 3200);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        camera.update();
        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();

        renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
        player.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
        renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();

    }
```